# Liferay 6.0.6 JSON API. Acces from External javascript

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, liferay

I need to find the way to access liferay portal data through its JSON api from a javascript client (by making AJAX calls).

I was able to find the adress for the API :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/tunnel-web/secure/json
```

which exist also as SOAP web service :

```
http://127.0.0.1/:8080/tunnel-web/secure/axis
```

After authentication, this soap version returns the list of services with wsdl descriptors but the json version doesn't show anything. ( with no error, an http status of 200)

I tried some request like this one :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/tunnel-web/secure/json?serviceClassName=com.liferay%C2%AD.portal.service.CountryServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=getCountries
```

Its returns a 404 error :  **Etat HTTP 404 - /tunnel-web/c/portal/status**
"Resource is not available"

What do I do wrong ?  And how can I access those data in JSON format ?

using **Liferay 6.06**

thanks for any help :)

**EDIT :**

Notice that I've passed the authentication process successfully. Either by giving loging password when requested by the browser or by adding them to the url :

```
http://login:password@127.0.0.1:8080/...
```

So the authentication is not the issue here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Sry  my fault ^^

as you can see the ServiceClassName in my request is corrupt with some "%C2%AD" characters :

```
http://login:password@127.0.0.1:8080/tunnel-web/secure/json?serviceClassName=com.liferay%C2%AD.portal.service.CountryServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=getCountries
```

That is the problem.

I've fixed it by removing them :

```
http://login:password@127.0.0.1:8080/tunnel-web/secure/json?serviceClassName=com.liferay.portal.service.CountryServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=getCountries
```

There was a clue [here](http://www.liferay.com/fr/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/6279705) : a topic about those json web services request with formating.

Comment: So, what's the status now? Have you got it working fine?

Comment: Yes, that's why I've posted this answer. (cannot accept it until tomorrow :/  )

Comment: Fine, if my hint was useful for you, thats enough for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Never tried! But I think liferay's secure webservices require credential for accessing.

First confirm your authentication type from portal-ext.properties as,

```
company.security.auth.type=screenName
```

then try accessing with following URL:

```
http://" + [userId / sreenName] + ":" + password + "@<server.com>:<port>/api/secure/axis/" + serviceName
```

**[REFERENCE](http://www.liferay.com/web/antonio.junior/blog/-/blogs/consuming-liferay-web-services)**

Comment: Thanks.  I've already went through this process, I'll update my question. The url you give is or liferay 6.1 and upper. Note also that I'm able to access SAOP web service with the axis url given for 6.0x but I need do use it with JSON format.